# Receiving an exception when trying to create and write to text file in external storage (Android Studio)

Tags: android

Here is my code snippet for a write method that I can call when I want to write data to this file.

public void Write(String file, String data)
    {

```
    File rootsd= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File datafolder= new File(rootsd.getAbsolutePath()+"/Data");
    if(!datafolder.isDirectory())
    {
        try
        {
            datafolder.mkdir();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error","Directory was not created");
        }
    }
    File datafile= new File(datafolder,file);
    try {
        if (!datafile.exists())
        {
            datafile.createNewFile();
        }
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(datafile));
            writer.write(data);
            writer.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", "File not found");
    }

}
```

For some reason this is automatically going right into the catch exception and returning File not Found, I'm not quite sure what the problem is and I cant seem to find a solution online. All help is appreciated, Thank You!

Edit: Logcat exception

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:941)
        at uwpsych.ocdstopwatch.Q1.Write(Q1.java:157)
        at uwpsych.ocdstopwatch.Q1.SaveData(Q1.java:142)
```

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Comment: Whether you defined permission in Manifest?

Comment: I have the write permission in my manifest, do I need the read permission as well?

Comment: Not needed read permission.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

if you want to read files add and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I actually have the first part in my manifest already. Do I need to have both in order to run this code? I guess it does make sense now that I think about it since I'm trying to check whether or not the directory and file exist. Ill try this and get back to you. Thank you!

Comment: no you don't need the second if you don't want to read files. A run your code and works...can you post the logcat to see the whole exception?

Comment: Which portion of the logcat would you need to see?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: uwpsych.ocdstopwatch, PID: 11157
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:941)
            at uwpsych.ocdstopwatch.Q1.Write(Q1.java:164)

Comment: did you try this on device or on emulator?

Comment: On a device. Sorry I cant paste the entire thing because of the character limit.

Comment: you can edit your question and post the whole exception there. And one more question. Which line is 164?

Comment: Edited my original question to include logcat, the line numbers mentionned are below

142:  Write("Data.txt","Hello");
157: datafile.createNewFile();

Comment: strange...try to remove these lines

if (!datafile.exists())
{
    datafile.createNewFile();
}

Comment: Same error, just shifts it to FileOutputStream f0ut = new FileOutputStream(datafile);

Comment: ah, sorry I had to add it in because I realized bufferedreader wouldnt work with external storage.

replace writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(datafile));
            writer.write(data);
            writer.close();

with FileOutputStream f0ut = new FileOutputStream(datafile);
        OutputStreamWriter dwrite = new OutputStreamWriter(f0ut);
        dwrite.write(data);
        dwrite.flush();
        dwrite.close();